# TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters, how can I fix this

Tags: node.js, github

```
/*Making http request to the api (Git hub)
create request
parse responce
wrap in a function
*/
var https = require("https");

var username = 'lynndor';
//CREATING AN OBJECT
var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: ' /users/'+ username +'/repos',
    method: 'GET'
};

var request = https.request(options, function(responce){
    var body = ''
    responce.on("data", function(chunk){
        body += chunk.toString('utf8')
    });
    responce.on("end", function(){
        console.log("Body", body);
    });
});
request.end();
```

> Im trying to create a request to the git hub api, the aim is to get the list repository for the specified you, but i keep getting the above mentioned error, please help

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No my proxy server is not checked

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your "path" variable contains space

`path: ' /users/'+ username +'/repos',`

Instead it should be

`path: '/users/'+ username +'/repos',`

Comment: where can i get a list of characters that need to be escaped in the path?

Comment: I think i get it. Sometimes it could be necessary to have strings url encoded before transmitting via node's http methods

Answer (score 111):

for other situation can be helpful

[JavaScript encodeURI() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)

```
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks. Facebook graph api works for hebrew (and I guess all other RTL languages) only if you use this approach.

Comment: another weird use case where this was useful is when I used supertest and jest to test my typescript API and my test URL had emojis in it. I wasn't able to send a request in that test without encoding it.

Answer (score 14):

> **Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode uri**
>
> **and `decodeURIComponent()` to decode uri**

Its because there are reserved characters in your uri. You will need to encode uri using inbuilt javascript function `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: encodeURIComponent('/users/'+ username +'/repos'),
    method: 'GET'
};
```

to decode encoded uri component you can use `decodeURIComponent(url)`

Answer (score 6):

Typically, ***you do not want to use `encodeURI()` directly.***  Instead, use `fixedEncodeURI()`. To quote [**MDN `encodeURI()` Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> If one wishes to follow the more recent RFC3986 for URLs, which makes square brackets reserved (for IPv6) and thus not encoded when forming something which could be part of a URL (such as a host), the following code snippet may help:
>
> `function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>       return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
>   }`

There is a similar issue with `encodeURIComponent()` (source: [**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)), as well as a similar `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` function.  These should be used, rather than the actual `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` function calls...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used:
>
> `function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>     return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>       return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>     });
>   }`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while trying to hit Elasticsearch's API. For me, it was due to Chinese characters in the Document's Title (in the Request I was sending). Switching to all English characters fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browser inspector uses abbreviation of long JSON object.
In my case, the data included unescaped characters such as '…' which should not be in http request.