# Zapier Unescaped Characters Bugs in code by zapier

Tags: zapier

I created my zap and Run javascirpt code by zapier, I get the following error:

```
We had trouble sending your test through.

> TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters
```

What does that mean? It is a problem about my code or the input data?

My code is:

```js
fetch(
  "test.s2.com.tr/Musteri/WebForm?_name=" +
    inputData._name +
    "&_email=" +
    inputData._email +
    "&_phone=" +
    inputData._phone +
    "&_source=" +
    inputData._source +
    "&_projeid=59b8d58fcec19d1f"
)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

Comment: can you post any of your code? namely, the url you're trying to request?

Comment: yes ı can post my code ,
fetch('https://test.s2.com.tr/Musteri/WebForm?_name=' + inputData._name + '&_email=' + inputData._email + '&_phone=' + inputData._phone + '&_source='+inputData._source+'&_projeid=59b8d58fcec19d1f')
  .then(function(res){
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  }).catch(callback);

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024779/typeerror-request-path-contains-unescaped-characters-how-can-i-fix-this). Basically, you have characters in one of those 4 inputs that doesn't belong in a url. Use `encodeURIComponent` to remedy that.

Comment: Actually the problem may be that input datas are included Turkish characters. 
How do I make sure it doesn't care about Turkish characters!!!

Comment: When I connected my zaps Lead A (is included turkish characters in inputdata ex; ş,ç,ğ,ö,ü....), Zap won't work.

Comment: See my answer - use `encodeURIComponent` on the input.